# ArcGIS -- Have a need for ArcGIS to correct addresses, via API, at speed. Possible?

Tags: arcgis

I have rough data coming in and I have a need to run it through address-correction in order to use it for other things.  That is, I have --

1313 M**uc**ckingbird Ln, Bowie, MD 20305

. . . and I need a tool that returns --

1313 M**o**ckingbird Ln, Bowie, MD 20305

I need to be able to do this programmatically for hundreds of thousands of addresses.  I keep raising this issue to management, and they keep sending me to ArcGIS installed in affiliated organizations.  I need to run this machine-to-machine and I need to be able to do it in bulk.

**Here's the problem --** I can't find anything in ArcGIS that provides this service via an API.  I need a fuzzy match, not more details on perfectly-entered address.

**The question --** does ArcGIS provide this capability, and if it does, can you tell me what feature or what term I should search for in the documentation?

I get the feeling that no matter how many times I express what our need is, my organization doesn't understand what I'm asking for.

Comment: https://prakhargurawa.medium.com/fuzzy-address-matching-algorithm-using-googles-geocoding-api-74c0d8d6a56f

Comment: Might be a better fit for https://gis.stackexchange.com